# Compile with Clang++ ignores CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH

Tags: c++, include-path, clang++

I am trying to compile a c++ project with clang++ and the CXX_FLAGS "-Wall -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11" on OS X. The project is a CMAKE project and requires cln and ginac to be included. However the compiler cannot find the according headers, when I give include statements like this:

```
#include <cln/cln.h>
```

or

```
#include <ginac/ginac.h>
```

although both libraries are installed in /usr/local/lib and their include directories (/usr/local/include/cln and /usr/local/include/ginac) exist. I've tried

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/local/include/cln:/usr/local/include/ginac )
```

but it does not show any effect, the error message stays the same:

```
fatal error: 'ginac/ginac.h' file not found
#include <ginac/ginac.h>
         ^
```

**Update:**

I managed to add compiler flags for verbose, which shows me, that the paths, where clang searches for the required headers are wrong, so the problem seems to resemble down to the question how to change these paths:

```
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../lib/clang/5.0/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks (framework directory)
End of search list.
```

whereas the required headers are still in /usr/local/include.

**Update 2**
Adding the CXX_FLAG

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

solves the problem - Where can I globally set this as a default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the CXX_FLAG

```
-I/usr/local/include
```

solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add to the discussion that I encountered almost the same issue as the author, where `include_directories("/usr/local/include/something")` in a `CMakeLists.txt` file did not work, however I was able to get around the problem using the approach recommended by adding a specific compiler flag to the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -I/usr/local/include/something")
```

Could this be a bug in cmake? This issue is only tangentially related, but may be of use to anyone attempting to get to the bottom of this:
https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/issues/19120

Answer (score 0):

You're specifying the full paths in the `CMakeFile.txt`, including the subdirectory. So that means when you include e.g. `<cln/cln.h>` the preprocessor will look for `/usr/local/include/cln/cln/cln.h`.

Try instead e.g.

```
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/local/include)
```

Comment: Good point, but that did not fix it - for me it seems that the changes I make to the CMakeLists.txt do not show any effect. I printed out the settings of the variables and all of them seem to be set correctly. I used make clean and even removed CMakeCache.txt during my tryouts, do I have to reset anything else?

Comment: @Modass Create a new sub-folder, and do e.g. `cmake ..`, this way you can be sure you have a clean setup. It might help.

Comment: okay, there is no output generated, guess I fix that first and then come back

Comment: I should see my changes, e.g. to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS also after invoking ccmake .. (after cmake ..), right? Because this is not the case, although I added set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS ${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} "-Wall -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++11") and
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH /usr/local/include)